# Realm database - react native

Tags: android, react-native, realm

I'm developing an android application with react-native that needs a database, I chose Realm.

I am a beginner in database development and would like to know if you can not send me an example of a Realm-made form in react-native.

I'm only thirteen and I'm just starting out in the programming world, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

congratulations on starting programming!
There are a few examples on our documentation page that might be helpful to you:
https://realm.io/docs/javascript/latest/

Comment: whether realm react-native work as client only database or can be worked both client and server database supporting online - offline sync up??